# Bootable USB creator

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-distribution, usb

I'm on Xubuntu 64 bit. Unetootin isn't detecting my USB. Startup USB creator doesn't work on all the ISOs. I want a bootable USB creator, that works on ubuntu 64 bit. It has to be updated and has a nice GUI and free.

Comment: I run on Ubuntu and have an xubuntu box too. Unebootin works fine with my 64 bit box, make sure full 7-zip is installed  prior using Unebootin.

Comment: @danijelc the software center version didn't work, the Linux version from their site  worked. Thank you

Comment: USC version are almost always few versions older than actual one

Comment: You can directly use `dd` but it's command-line. Example : `dd if=my_iso_image.iso of=/dev/my_usb_stick`.

Comment: Can either Danijel write or Fischer write an answer.
or Andre.
a dd answer would also be good
So it can be accepted.

Comment: @Oxinabox anyone can, not me, I don't like answering my own question unless I really must do that

Comment: @André would you answer the question so I can accept it, since your answer is something I didn't know before asking the question

Comment: Here you go, answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use [`dd`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29) which is included by default in most distributions, however it's not GUI-based.

Example usage :

```
dd if=/path/to/your/image.iso of=/dev/sdX
```

This won't show any progress though, the command will end once the process is complete.

Replace `/dev/sdX` with the actual path to your USB drive - note that this will copy the entire ISO filesystem to the drive, so it'll actually behave more like an USB CD drive rather than a flash drive and some BIOSes may not like that and won't boot from it (but personally I never had such an issue).

Comment: Make certain you have your source and destinations set correctly . . . dd will overwrite whatever you point it at.

Answer (score 0):

After trying a few, I settled on [Ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html).

You can select which .ISO you wish to boot from - just add and remove the .ISO files as you wish :)